# Vert.x Web , GraphQL , Hibernate Reactive

Tags: java, hibernate, graphql, vert.x, hibernate-reactive

I am going to write an Api with Vert.x web and GraphQL
I have connected with the database with Hibernate reactive

```java
    public void start(final Promise<Void> startPromise)
    {
        try
        {
            vertx.executeBlocking(e ->
            {
                try
                {
                    hibernateConfig();
                    e.complete();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    e.fail(exception.getCause());
                }

            }).onComplete(event ->
            {
                try
                {
                    runServer(startPromise);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }).onFailure(Throwable::printStackTrace);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void runServer(final Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception
    {
        final HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();

        final Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

        router.post("/graphql").handler(super::graphqlHandler);

        // register `/graphiql` endpoint for the GraphiQL UI
        final GraphiQLHandlerOptions graphiqlOptions = new GraphiQLHandlerOptions().setEnabled(true);
        router.route("/graphiql/*").handler(GraphiQLHandler.create(graphiqlOptions));

        final URL resource = getClass().getResource("/static");

        if (resource != null) router.route("/static/*").handler(StaticHandler.create(resource.getFile()));
        else throw new Exception("Cannot set static");

        httpServer.requestHandler(router).listen(PORT , "localhost" , event ->
        {
            if (event.succeeded())
            {
                System.out.printf("Server run on port %d!\n" , PORT);
                startPromise.complete();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error run server!");
                startPromise.fail(event.cause());
            }
        });
    }

    private void hibernateConfig()
    {
        Uni.createFrom().deferred(Unchecked.supplier(() ->
        {
            final Configuration configuration = new Configuration().setProperties(getHibernateProperties());

            final Set<Class<?>> entitiesClasses = getEntitiesClasses();

            if (entitiesClasses != null)
            {
                for (final Class<?> entity : entitiesClasses) configuration.addAnnotatedClass(entity);
            }
            else logger.error("Cannot found entities");

            final StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new ReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .addService(Server.class , this)
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

            final StandardServiceRegistry registry = builder.build();

            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry).unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);

            if (!sessionFactory.isOpen()) throw new RuntimeException("Session is close!");

            logger.info("✅ Hibernate Reactive is ready");

            return Uni.createFrom().voidItem();
        })).convert().toCompletableFuture().join();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties()
    {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER , "org.mysql.jdbc.DRIVER");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.URL , "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.USER , "USENAME");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.PASS , "PASSWORD");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT , "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_DATABASE_ACTION , "create");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.SHOW_SQL , "false");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.POOL_SIZE , "10");
        return properties;
    }
```

So far it doesn't give any error and creates the entities

The error is given when I want to do an Insert

```java
    public Future<UsersDto> addUserTest(final DataFetchingEnvironment environment)
    {
        return Future.future(event ->
        {
            final AddUsersDto addUsersDto = Dto.mapped(environment.getArguments() , "user" , AddUsersDto.class);

            final Users user = UsersMapper.toUsers(addUsersDto);

            try
            {
                vertx.executeBlocking(e ->
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                sessionFactory.withTransaction(
                                                (session , transaction) ->
                                                        session.persist(user)
                                                                .chain(session::flush)
                                        )
                                        .invoke(() -> e.complete(user))

                                        .onFailure()
                                        .invoke(e::fail)

                                        .await()
                                        .indefinitely();
                            }
                            catch (Exception exception)
                            {
                                exception.printStackTrace();
                                e.fail(exception.getCause());
                            }
                        })
                        .onComplete(e -> event.complete(UsersMapper.toUsersDto((Users) e.result())))
                        .onFailure(e -> event.fail(e.getCause()));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                event.complete(UsersDto.builder().build());
            }
        });
    }
```

Error:

```java
sessionFactory.withTransaction(
                (session , transaction) ->
                        session.persist(user)
                                .chain(session::flush)
        )
        .invoke(() -> e.complete(user))

        .onFailure()
        .invoke(e::fail)

        .await()
        .indefinitely(); // This line gives an error
```

Error text:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000068: This method should exclusively be invoked from a Vert.x EventLoop thread; currently running on thread 'vert.x-worker-thread-1'

Please help me if anyone knows the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are running everything in the worker thread (using `executeBlocking`).

If you are writing reactive code, you don't need to wait for the result to be available.

The code should look something like this:

```java
    public Future<UsersDto> addUserTest(final DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
        return Future.future(event -> {
            final AddUsersDto addUsersDto = Dto.mapped(environment.getArguments() , "user" , AddUsersDto.class);
            final Users user = UsersMapper.toUsers(addUsersDto);
            sessionFactory
                .withTransaction( (session , tx) -> session.persist(user) )
                .subscribe().with( event::complete, event::fail )
        });
    }
```

You also don't need to flush because there's a transaction.

[There is a working example on the Hibernate Reactive repository](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/blob/main/integration-tests/verticle-postgres-it/src/main/java/org/hibernate/reactive/it/verticle/ProductVerticle.java)